# New Light Switch Fried

Tags: electrical

I noticed one of my dimmer switches in my kitchen that controls the lights under cabinets stopped working months ago but I never got around to replacing it till now. I replaced it with a brand new switch, the exact same switch. (Now I’m not to versed in the electrical field but I’ve replaced a lot of switches and outlets over the years, anything electrical more than simple switches I won’t touch.)

So I hooked up the switch exactly how to old one was hooked up, and the old switch was working fine for the first two years we’ve lived here, but as soon as I turned the breaker on the switch made a loud pop sound and smelled like an old cap gun and obviously didn’t work. If someone could give me some insight that would be great.

This picture is when I first opened it up. This is before I touched anything. The switch on the right is the switch in question:

[image]

Comment: Typical would be a short - e.g., exposed metal of hot wire or a screw touched ground wire or metal box. Pictures would help.

Comment: If both had exactly one red wire, one black wire, and one green wire then hooking the new on up "exactly the same" probably should have worked -- which does suggest that either you didn't get it exactly the same, or one of your connections wasn't made well and either exposed conductor or came free and thus shorted against something else.

Comment: What are those unterminated red wires with red flags on them?  What do the flags say?   Did your new switch have one of those too?   What happens if you take the two black wires that are normally connected to the switch and connect them directly to one another?  What should happen is the lights come on full brightness.  If instead they pop the breaker, you have a problem somewhere in your home wiring.

Comment: I'm concerned that I see at least 3 cables, but **only 2** ground wires going into the green nut, and I can't tell if the bare ground wire from the wire nut to the switch greens is actually joined in there, or not. I made the picture a little brighter so I could follow the black wires, and that wiring *appears* to be correct. But is there bare copper showing on one of the neutrals? @jay613 those extra reds with the flags are if you want to use it for a 3-way, typically.

Comment: Kurt if you can provide a new picture with the wires unraveled a little more and with better focus and lighting of everything inside the box including the back of the box, that would be helpful.  Not disconnected, just unraveled so it's easier to follow them.

Comment: A little brown staining on two neutrals in the middle of the pic --- is that dirt or were they burned?

Comment: @jay613 many of the new switches I've installed recently (maybe it's mostly a smart switch thing) are set up for 1-way or 3-way operation and you leave the extra traveler unattached (but wirenutted) if you're only hooking up a 1-way. That's my interpretation, but let's wait for the OP to respond.

Comment: It's _fantastic_ that you have a before picture! Most people forget that. Can you also show us the _after_ picture? There's a possibility that it looks right to you, but that one of the electricians here will spot something missing.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far. Unfortunately I just left for the weekend but will update it when I get back. Nothing looks burnt,just dirty. I’m thinking the original switch popped at some point months ago when I noticed it stopped working and when I installed the new one the same thing happened. I just don’t know what would cause it to short because I never opened it up or touched anything on that circuit

Comment: The problem might be at or before the light.  A loose hot touching something it should not, will start the popping.  I would also put wire nuts on those two extra red wires.

Comment: Yeah, replacing a fried switch with a new one and having it fry isn't _too_ surprising if you didn't track down what caused the first one to go.

Comment: Hard to tell for sure, but those orange and white wire nuts look like they haven't been twisted enough, as the wires coming out the bottoms have no tight twists visible.